# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, statistics, moderation

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Worldbuilding breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 17         19
Users destroyed                                  43          0
Users deleted                                     6          0
Users contacted                                  40          0
User suspensions lifted early                     2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           289      3,414
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue              300      3,856
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        163      5,170
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               48        626
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue               335      4,010
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              145     12,668
Tags merged                                       4          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             2          6
Tag synonyms created                             14          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               82        171
Questions protected                             121         69
Questions migrated                               22          4
Questions flagged⁴                               31      2,063
Questions closed                                579      1,932
Question flags handled⁴                       1,031      1,063
Posts unlocked                                    2          9
Posts undeleted                                  29        109
Posts locked                                      3        184
Posts deleted⁵                                  552      1,955
Posts bumped                                      0          4
Escalations to the CM team                        7          0
Comments undeleted                              126          0
Comments flagged                                136      2,065
Comments deleted⁶                            11,302      4,898
Comment flags handled                         1,605        596
Answers flagged                                 317      2,915
Answer flags handled                          1,257      1,975
All comments on a post moved to chat            339          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...