# I was answering a question in "worldbuilding" when it was closed in my face. I would like to know who did this

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I think it is not a good practice to close doors on one's face! My English is not good? It's ok. Tell me that. I'll accept it and I'll  make an effort to make it better. I have let an incomplete answer because a bad educated person closed a door on my face!

Comment: Wait, what is the relationship between not being good in English *as an answerer* and have the *question* closed? Why do you think they're related ^^'?

Comment: Besides, can you give a link to the question? It's to know what triggered your reaction :).

Comment: As a practical advice: You can always copy the text of your answer into Google Keep, or StackEdit, or SimpleNote, or whatever else free web-based note-taking application. This way, if the question is closed you still have your work and can re-use it.

Answer (score 7):

Closing questions off topic questions is an integral part of the stack exchange format. If closing questions didn't prevent people from answering them then the act of closing questions would be meaningless.

There isn't a system to indicate that a question has pending draft answers and in the eyes of the community moderation process if the question *as written* has issues it shouldn't receive any answers. Unfortunately this occasionally results in race conditions where you can't submit an answer to a question that was closed while composing the draft.

When you gain sufficient reputation you can see who voted to close questions. I can't remember what the rep threshold is for seeing who voted to close a question. I can tell you that it was very likely 5 regular members of the community who voted to close it.

Comment: On top of that nobody can see if there is anybody else busy writing an answer.

Comment: SO doesn't display that information, and I don't think they are interested in spending the engineering resources to do so. If a question has issues that result in it being closed we don't want people answering the question. We don't penalize people who have already answered the question but to allow for any answers after closure defeats the whole point of closing questions in the first place.

Comment: The names are hidden on the close notice but users can view the names of the those who voted to close a question by visiting the timeline or the edit history. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/223115/timeline.

Answer (score 3):

I've had a dozen or more questions over the years closed half-way through an answer I was writing. Once or twice I even thought the answer I was writing was some of my best work.

It happens - it's a consequence of the fact that 1-5 people voted to close the question before I could finish. It's not an insult to me - they don't (and can't) know that I'm trying to pound out an answer. It's just the way a self-moderated site works.

Welcome to the club. We meet on Thursdays.

Comment: Strategy session: if you're banging out a really boss answer and you're pretty sure the query is going to be closed, you can always post a placeholder answer, then edit even after the query is closed. Of course! I'm not recommending that we answer questions that are likely to be closed! -- But...you know...

Comment: @elemtilas That's true! But (a) I rarely notice the VTC status of a question I'm busy answering, (b) even if the VTC status is zero, it can close in minutes. I've answered questions I thought were reasonable but that others deemed worth closing (just as others have answered questions I deemed worth closing). I suppose club members could get into the habit of posting placeholder answers (and hope no one flags them as "not an answer" before we complete our edits!)... but I suspect the real answer here is, "it happens, sorry. But life's good! So don't worry about it."

Comment: "It happens, sorry." How true! And that's happened to me a few times as well. In that case, the answer just gets added to a file of worldbuilding queries I've answered over the years. And yes, a query being pulled out from under one by the **Commisariat of Five** should never be taken personally or quite so angstily as we see in the query!

Answer (score 1):

Let's keep in mind that only around [7% of closed questions get reopened](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9609/2021-a-year-in-moderation), it is always safer to never be the first to answer, wait a few hours and see how it goes, just to save your own time and mental sanity.

Alternativelly, re ask the question yourself and answer it yourself.
There are internet websites and applications that allow you to go back in time and recover all your lost material, but generelly just going back to the previous page will save all that you have written.

Like now, if I send this post then press ''back page'' button, it will automatically bring me to the edit section.

Another stragegy is to not write the answer directly on this website, write it somewhere else then copy paste it, I juggest visual studio because it is black screened and it counts your lines, it also saves the file even if your computer crashes without you saving it.

Answer (score -2):

**I really agree with the asker and I *upvoted* this question.**

From many answerer's perspective, also mine, topics get closed too quickly on WB imho, even for first answers. Sometimes there's long answers, because of the subject. These take time. When starting research and answer, why would you take 1-2 close votes into account ? You may disagree.. but suddenly, it's getting 20:00 PM European time and the topic gets closed, because some new peer-mod folks come online and start their reviews. Close-Close-Close and the three votes arrive before you can finish. I recognize the situation.. and the *frustration*..

The reason given is often "they have to edit" but I don't see many openers do that. I tried a few times myself, with peer mod privs, to "salvage" a topic. But it is difficult to be on time. The opener.. just flies by again 12 hours later and finds his/her topic closed.

Most times, when answerers put a protest, we'll get the reply *"you don't answer questions that need to be closed"* but.. at first, it wasn't closed.. and when you have invested 1-2 hours in an answer (that happens), it's difficult to acknowledge that there is *any* reason your submit will bounce!

My proposal would be: ease up. Don't go rush rush with these reviews. And enter the question list first, don't go review right away. Read questions that interest you, answer them. Then do the reviews. I skip most, actually. If something is unanswerable, don't worry, few answers will follow. If something is off topic for WB, the answers can still remain *on topic*, close it next day.

And please give more advice.. also to 500+ points askers.. the rules here are complicated. Try to comment in a positive way, without attacking the opener's intent, with words like "fishing" and "misconception", like it happens now. That will not motivate to go editing a question. *Explain* to the opener, why a vote to close is set and promise you will reverse it on a good edit. Sometimes I see topics without any comment explaining the close vote. Users don't even know who closed or why.

Let's have some more respect, too. Not everyone knows what "unanswerable" is, or the "book test". Someone asking about a hypothetical subject, without any science or reality tags, should not be bothered with "opinion based", or "single answer" or "fact-based" general SE constraints. As long as the (single) question - and its answers - help finding *scientifically plausible* explanations for the reader, it should be allowed on SE/WB, imho.

**Suppose we would want 100% SE-compliant quality..**

If SE wants to avoid these frustrations on SE/WB.. be compliant [to SE culture](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/?_ga=2.171167656.92693083.1638304628-995428532.1603487676) around subjective questions, you'd have to comply to rules like *"Stack Exchange is about questions with objective, factual answers. "*..

If you really want to impose that, change the forum software to let the opener choose between science-based, hard-science and reality-check tags. One of these tags is obligatory.. and questions *and* answers should comply to it. It would reduce the audience, reduce the scope, and eliminate 40-50 other tags. There are no science-based merfolk, or science-based dragons, or science-based FTL, or science based life on neutron stars. All these questions can be closed immediately.

Comment: Though the OP posted a rant more than a question, this is not even answering the OP's question.

Comment: @L.Dutch I tried to address the problem of fast and unexplained closures on WB. I think that could have caused this "rand" to appear on meta. I agree, *who* closed something is secondary.. but I recognized the frustration. Below peer-mod level points (3000?) you *can't see* who voted to close your question. I don't know the topic this is about, but when there are 5 close votes and no one gives an explanation in a comment, you can expect the style of the complaint will not be friendly..

Comment: Please don't post incomplete answers solely with the intention of circumventing site policy.

Comment: @sphennings isn't WB-Meta the place to *discuss* WB policy ? I think the current close procedure using reviews with 20-50 peer mods is unpractical. The moment of closure is determined by the 5th review "close" and that moment is arbitrary. What about a separate review queue ? there are solutions.. and I haven't said I don't agree with WB rules.

Comment: I'm talking about the behavior you advocate on the main site *"I put the summary first, so I keep my edit slot when it gets closed."* posting incomplete answers in an effort to post an answer after a question is closed is an attempt to circumvent the restriction of posting new answers on closed questions. We prevent posts on closed questions for a reason. We also discourage users from posting low quality answers, which a summary only answer would be. Don't do this.

Comment: Well @sphennings ok, I'll change the clickbait title of this answer.. But you have to admit, for someone who agrees there is an *issue* with closures, my answer is a *valid* answer and I will make sure it is, by complying to your request.

Comment: @Goodies We're more lenient with assessing whether posts answer the question on Meta than we are on main but this seems like an attempt to start a discussion where you air your grievances with closures that are unrelated to the OP's question. If you really want to discuss site policy I'd suggest creating a separate meta post. It will get more attention and allow for more participation from the community at large.

Comment: @sphennings imho my answer is very related to the question.. I actually put exactly the same cause as JoinJBH did. The difference is, I provided a deviant opinion about it. I see an *issue* with the current closure procedure, that's all. The other two answers explain site policy.

Comment: I've put an edit, added a closing paragraph.

Comment: I don't see what anything you've posted has to do with OP's question of "Who closed the question" What I do see is that you have some strong opinions about how questions are closed on this site. If you actually want to propose changes to site policy, make a separate meta post about that. Don't rant on unrelated pages.

Comment: @Sphennings Like anyone has posted here is technically off-topic to the "who dun' it' question... You included :).

Comment: @Goodies I don't understand the last paragraph about "openers" and tags. What do you mean that these tags are obligatory? Do you mean in the context of aiming non-subjective questions?

Comment: @Tortliena I'm considering to delete my answer, I don't like downvotes. What I meant with the last paragraph: if these 3 tags (one of them, or a combination) would be obligatory, all these extra WB rules and exceptions involving "subjective" or "opinion" or "possible logic" criteria would not be needed, the SE guideline would do. Only questions that require a single, fact-based answer would be allowed. WB would become a scientific community only designing *plausible* worlds, rather than a Q&A for writers.

Comment: @Goodies I'm not sure that would solve entirely it as questions could still get closed "in your face". There'd be just one reason less for it to happen ^^.  Most likely 2 downvotes are about off-topic, but it's not in fact if we look at the underlying issue. Even if I don't entirely agree on the direction you wish to take, I agree it's an issue with the way SE works and try to suggest solutions to this. That's why I didn't upvote or downvote. I don't think you should delete something just because of peer pressure, so speak your mind :).

Comment: @Tortliena don't get me wrong I don;t advocate these heavy restrictions, I'd like to have the number of close criteria reduced on WB, not make closing easier. The democracy here implies there are hundreds of peer-mods. They know all these details ? My impression is people often help close topics on subjective criteria and preference, or they just vote along with certain "crack" members who take the initiative. The most strict interpretation will always win.